# Question: How do I write the command to find the customer who placed an order number 12345?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Sales** database:

- Customer (custId, lastName, firstName, address, phone, creditLimit)
- Order (orderNumber, date, total, custID)
- LineItem (orderNumber, itemNumber, qtyOrdered).
- Item (itemNumber, itemName, price)

For the Sales database shown above, write the SQL command to find the name and address of the customer who placed order number 12345.

Comment: What have **you** tried so far?? We'll be glad to help if you run into any problems - but SO isn't a **code-writing service** where you just dump your requirements and get back the code for that ...... ***YOU*** need to show some effort first!

Comment: Try this:
`SELECT c.firstname
   ,c.lastname
   ,c.address
FROM Order O
INNER JOIN Customer C
 ON C.custID = O.custID
WHERE O.OrderNumber = 12345`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) advises *"Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    firstName + ' ' + lastName  [Customer]
,   [address]
,   [phone]
from        [Order] o
inner join  [Customer] c    on  c.custId = o.custId
where       o.orderNumber = '12345'
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: [While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers). Also worth reading the "How do I answer homework" in [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Given the name, it's a fair guess that `OrderNumber` is a numeric type. By quoting the 12345, you're requiring SQL to convert it from a string.

Comment: I agree Richard, however, should the `OrderNumber` field have `alpha numeric` values, the script would still work. Based on what was given to us in the question, I had to make a call to include for `Alpha Numeric` Values.

Comment: Great! Please mark my answer as the answer then @DarrinRodden. :-)